# Send email to users of different time zones, at same time of day.

Tags: email, scheduled-apex, time-dependent-workflow, timezone

I want to send email to users at 11:00 PM or say end of the day, When certain criteria is met. I tried to accomplish this by Time-Based Workflow rule, but failed, as we cannot run a workflow rule on a specific time of day..

Now I am trying to send email with Scheduled Apex. Now the problem I am facing is that, some users are located in different time zones. They receive emails at different time, not 11 PM.

What is the way out?

Comment: Just schedule it hourly and find all the users with the offset that puts them currently at 11PM.